# React - Why is my stylesheet not found? Error 404

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm, http-status-code-404

Here is my root HTML file. As you can see, it has no problem getting styles from Bootstrap (this functionality is working just fine). When I open up index.html in the browser at localhost:8080 (running a server through a webpack command), It cannot find the stylesheet! This is something I don't understand. Please help. Thank you.

BTW.. stylesheet.css is at the same directory level as index.html AND index.js. How come the bootstrap stylesheet is getting picked up but not my stylesheet?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Weather App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor automatically loads all style sheets. I've seen it recommended to put them in the /client/stylesheets, or /imports/ui/css folder.

You don't have need to put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />` . Try removing that line and see if you can see your styles applied to your page.

The reason `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`  is working for you is because it is loading from an external address. It is hard-coded on your html and not being managed by meteor.  I don't recommend it, but if you wanted to do the same thing with your style sheet, you would put it in the /public folder, and use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" />`. But Meteor is designed to manage all the style sheets for you, so best not to do this.

Lastly, if you want to control the order style sheets are imported, you can specify `import '/client/stylesheet.css';`       // import CSS from absolute path  - see here for clarity: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#intro-to-import-export

Comment: What difference does putting it in the /public folder create?

Comment: your public folder is what is treated as your root directory.  Everything else is magically loaded and managed by meteor, but 'something' in the public folder can be accessed by  `src="/something"`.